# What makes neuromorphic computing architecture more efficient than von Neumann

Tags: complexity-theory, machine-learning, parallel-computing

What makes neuromorphic architectures more efficient (less heat and power consumption) than von Neumann architecture for complex tasks? Except inspiration from biological systems, what are some formal results on this?
Any reference to books or articles is appreciated as well.

Comment: arxiv.org/abs/1206.3227

Comment: The idea of the paper is very interesting, thanks.

Comment: in a way this is more an EE/physics question. note also youre "comparing apples & oranges"

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3181466/ (specifically the citations in Figure 1's caption.)  The comparison is a bit silly though: they're comparing single neurons, and it isn't clear how many neurons vs. how many digital computations would be required to implement any algorithm other than "simulate the Hodgkin-Huxley system of nonlinear differential equations."  To do a real comparison you need to compare a digital circuit of equally low precision and implemented with something like [adiabatic charge recovery logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing).